# How can I group based on date and type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table but I havent been able to group it, by date and card type, also it should sum the values...I am having issues because of the id i think

```
   OrderID | OrderDate  | CCType      |  Processed
    ----------- ---------------------------
    451    |2012-02-27 | AMEX        |   10.56
    452    |2012-02-27 | VISA        |   20.00
    453    |2012-02-27 | MASTER CARD |   5.00
    454    |2012-02-27 | OTHER       |   16.00
    455    |2012-02-27 | AMEX        |   10.00
    456    |2012-02-26 | VISA        |   11.00
    457    |2012-02-26 | MASTER CARD |   12.00
    457    |2012-02-26 | OTHER       |   5.00
```

It would need to endup something like this

```
OrderDate  | CCType      |  Processed
-----------------------------------------
2012-02-27 | AMEX       | 20.56
2012-02-27 | VISA       | 20.00
2012-02-27 | MASTER CARD| 5.00
2012-02-27 | OTHER      | 16.00    
2012-02-26 | AMEX       | 0.00
2012-02-26 | VISA       | 11.00
2012-02-26 | MASTER CARD| 12.00
2012-02-26 | OTHER      | 5.00
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is to get this line

```
2012-02-26 AMEX        0,00
```

If you don't need it the other answers have what you want.

```
declare @Order table
(
  OrderID int,
  OrderDate date,
  CCType varchar(20),
  Processed money
)

insert into @Order values
(    451,    '2012-02-27', 'AMEX',           10.56),
(    452,    '2012-02-27', 'VISA',           20.00),
(    453,    '2012-02-27', 'MASTER CARD',    5.00),
(    454,    '2012-02-27', 'OTHER',          16.00),
(    455,    '2012-02-27', 'AMEX',           10.00),
(    456,    '2012-02-26', 'VISA',           11.00),
(    457,    '2012-02-26', 'MASTER CARD',    12.00),
(    457,    '2012-02-26', 'OTHER',          5.00)

select D.OrderDate, C.CCType, sum(coalesce(T.Processed,  0)) as Processed
from (values('AMEX'),
            ('VISA'),
            ('MASTER CARD'),
            ('OTHER')) as C(CCType)
  cross join (select distinct OrderDate
              from @Order) as D(OrderDate)
  left outer join @Order as T
    on D.OrderDate = T.OrderDate and
       C.CCType = T.CCType              
group by D.OrderDate, C.CCType
order by D.OrderDate desc, C.CCType
```

Result:

```
OrderDate  CCType      Processed
---------- ----------- ---------------------
2012-02-27 AMEX        20,56
2012-02-27 MASTER CARD 5,00
2012-02-27 OTHER       16,00
2012-02-27 VISA        20,00
2012-02-26 AMEX        0,00
2012-02-26 MASTER CARD 12,00
2012-02-26 OTHER       5,00
2012-02-26 VISA        11,00
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this

```
select OrderDate ,ltrim(rtrim(CCType)) as CCType  ,sum(Processed )
from [Order] group by  OrderDate ,ltrim(rtrim(CCType))
```

Comment: well it did not work :( it still shows two lines for AMEX, it should add them).. i think because Processed is different? (the amount) - I will, but i am still stuck .. I would give you the answer... no problem..

Comment: Basically for date 2/27/2012 it still shows two rows for AMEX while it should only show one with the amounts added

Comment: @user710502 - I thinks it require to apply the trim function...that will resolve issue if there is any space after or before....because this shoudl work as per your data..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select OrderDate, CCType, Sum(Processed)
from [Order]
group by OrderDate, CCType
```